# android : ignore conditional array adaptor for spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I am new to Android. I tried to form a conditional adaptor (depends on a String variable) for different string arrays.

```
    TextView textPrompt;
    textPrompt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textprompt);
    final String acType = i.getStringExtra("type");
    textPrompt.setText(acType);
    if (acType == "400G"){
    spinnerSurface = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSurface);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSurface = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.surface_option_1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterSurface.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerSurface.setAdapter(adapterSurface);

    }
    else if (acType != "400G"){
        spinnerSurface = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSurface);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSurface = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.surface_option, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterSurface.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerSurface.setAdapter(adapterSurface);

    }

    spinnerSurface.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener() { 
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, 
                int position, long id) { 
            TextView tx = (TextView)v; 
            Log.i("\n\nid",String.valueOf(tx.getText()));
        } 
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        } 
    });
```

I use a textPrompt to check value of acType. No matter acType is "400G" or not "400G", program will take acType as not "400G" thus R.array.surface_option is taken instead of R.array.surface_option1.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a Java question, not android - you should not compare `String`s using `==`, use `equals()` instead

```
if (acType != null && acType.equals("400G")){
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

As `String`s are objects, `==` compares references, which most likely will be different in your case for equal strings.

Comment: Vladmir,thanks for your prompt reply. I copied your code and still not working.

Comment: thats strange. are you sure you resource for `surface_option_1` is correct? anyway, you can try adding `Log.d("EqualityTest", acType + " is equal to 400G: " + acType.equals("400G"));` before `if` statement to check what it returns. also, if `acType` can be "400g" for examle, consider using `equalsIgnoreCase("400G")` instead of `equals()`

Comment: Vladmir, I viewed the LogCat, it is "400G is equal to 400G: false". So acType is really "400G", but it said "false" ???? What happened?

Comment: Vladmir, I got it. acType was " 400G". Using acType.trim(), problem solved. Really appreciate your help. And I have learned "Log" from you too.